# does not find the namespace Telerik.Sitefinity.Cloud.WindowsAzure in the class AzureWebRole.cs

Tags: windows, azure, telerik, cloud, sitefinity

but when he builds the solution its seems of all the refrences are missing and does not compile because it does not find the namespace Telerik.Sitefinity.Cloud.WindowsAzure in the class AzureWebRole.cs

Comment: Do you use Nuget for the Sitefinity assemblies? If so make sure your solution is set to automatically restore missing nuget packages.

Comment: If your are not using Nuget under references in the project does that assembly have a yellow warning? If yes you will need to restore the dll to the bin. Use the project managers empty project to help

Answer (score 0):

The sitefinity project creator puts all of the required dlls in the bin folder and adds the references in the project to them in this location.  In my opinion, this is not a good strategy as the bin folder *should* be generated from external sources, but that's how it goes at the moment.

Your options as I see them are :

1. Copy the dlls to a shared folder and change the references' HintPaths to this location.
2. Check the bin folder into source control (gak!)
3. Change the project to use the Nuget package strategy for the sitefinity references.